# Netbeans IDE 7.3.1 logger

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

My logger shortcut not working on netbeans ide 7.3.1

But when I use netbeans 7.3 it's working.

My problem is when I type log then press tab button not completing a logger code.

but in 7.3 it's working.

```
log - in netbeans 7.3.1 not working
Logger.getLogger(EmailOff.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "message"); - in netbeans 7.3 working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the reason that in your netbeans 7.3.1 configure, you should check your setting in  the settings menu->general->code complete->java language, and in the code hint blank you can type in all your alphabetical characters in it.  Then whatever you type in for instance `log`,  netbeans will automatically complete the rest code for you.